# Problema no ajax

Tags: javascript

Não estou conseguindo obter a resposta na requisição do ajax. O código não confirma se está funcionando ou não.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function iniciarAjax(){
        var ajax = false;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
            try{
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHttpRequest");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                    ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttpRequest");
                }catch(ex){
                    ajax = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return ajax;
    }
    var conectarServidor = iniciarAjax();
    if(conectarServidor){
        conectarServidor.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(conectarServidor.readyState == 4){
                if(conectarServidor.status == 200{
                    alert("Tudo certo")
                }
                else{
                    alert("Problema ocorreu")
                }
            }
            conectarServidor.open("GET","http://localhost/locadora/cadastro.php");
            conectarServidor.send();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Coloquei o código que tinhas usado na resposta aqui, para estar na pergunta e não numa resposta, pois fazia parte da pergunta. Podes sempre clicar em [edit]  para adicionar detalhes à pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

As linhas

```
conectarServidor.open("GET","http://localhost/locadora/cadastro.php");
conectarServidor.send();
```

têm de testar fora de `.onreadystatechange = function(){` pois essa é a função que vai correr quando o ajax começar a mudar o seu estado. Tendo aí dentro ela nunca vai correr porque o `.send()` nunca foi executado.

```js
function iniciarAjax() {
  var ajax = false;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    try {
      ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHttpRequest");
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttpRequest");
      } catch (ex) {
        ajax = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return ajax;
}
var conectarServidor = iniciarAjax();
if (conectarServidor) {
  conectarServidor.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (conectarServidor.readyState == 4) {
      if (conectarServidor.status == 200) {
          alert("Tudo certo")
        } else {
          alert("Problema ocorreu")
        }
      }
    }
  }
  conectarServidor.open("GET", "http://localhost/locadora/cadastro.php");
  conectarServidor.send();
}
```

Comment: Fiz como você tinha mencionado. Coloquei fora. Mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Comment: @AlexandreSantosdaCruz falta um `)` depois de `200`, dá uma olhada aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/8zdjcyna/

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Então, o meu problema era ter colocado o código dentro das chaves?

Comment: Uma pergunta. O código agora responde se está funcionando ou não. Quando eu coloquei a url para a página php como método POST que criei está acusando um erro. Então, o problema está nela?

Comment: Consegui, resolver. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @AlexandreSantosdaCruz ótimo. Se a resposta resolveu o teu problema podes clicar e marcar como aceite.